# Upgrade soldered GPU

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, motherboard, gpu

I have a few questions about GPU upgrading, my laptop is good but the GPU is really bad, if it was a better one I could play most recent games on medium-high instead of lower quality.
My laptop is an Alienware M14X R2, the GPU is a Nvidia GT 650M, but it is soldered in the motherboard, and I wanted to know.
Can I replace it? Just buy a new GPU and replace it somehow without replacing the motherboard?
If not then if I buy a new motherboard and a GPU wich motherboard would be good, and do I have to solder it? Or can i just leave it tapped inside(not really but you get the point), to upgrade it easier if I want?
And that leads to my last question, if I bought a motherboard with a soldered GPU could I replace it and what would be the cheapest or easiest(like Ebay or something) place I could find one?

Comment: Short answer yes, **if** there is a compatible GPU on the market. Longer answer is probably no, **because** there are no pin compatible GPUs on the market.

Comment: The two versions of the motherboard that came in that laptop only supported the 650M GPU.[Source](http://en.community.dell.com/owners-club/alienware/f/3746/t/19534366.aspx)

Comment: Please remove the pointless vulgar offensive language from your question.  Your not going to replace the motherboard the CPU not the GPU on your laptop

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible for a large number of reasons. These include being unable to provide enough power for the GPU, being unable to remove the additional heat it generates, and the virtual impossibility of working on these kinds of components without specialized tools and expertise.

Answer (score 1):

Buying a new motherboard isnt going to be possible either

these systems are only made with specific size dimensions and most likely all the motherboards that will fit in your laptop case and support the screen wil have the same hardware spec

They aren't interchangeable like with regular desktops

so simply put no u cant change out hardware.

Answer (score 1):

You can however purchase an EXP GDC to run a desktop video card externally. It is being done by a number of people with great success.
http://www.banggood.com/EXP-GDC-Laptop-External-PCI-E-Graphics-Card-p-934367.html
a youtuber shows how it works and all instructions are also on purchase page 
Have fun...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qs_13V2OMLI

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.